# Create an object with type defined by string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I am trying to create an instance of an object with a type defined from a string.

Here's the code I have done (Note that I am in a wcf webservice):

```
namespace CreeContact.WebServices
{

    public class BaseObject  
    {

    }

    public class test : BaseObject
    {
        public string name;
        public test()
        {
            name = "Default";
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Object
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public void createobject(string classname, string idobjectsession)
        {

            ***ERROR HERE (Value cannot be null. Type.GetType(classname) return null) ----- > *** BaseObject objecttocreate = (BaseObject)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(classname));
            HttpContext.Current.Session[idobjectsession] = objecttocreate;
        }


    }
}
```

So when I call (from javascript) my webservice method "CreateObject" with the parameter "test" (Name of the class I want to create an instance of), the `Type.GetType(classname)` always return null...

Im stuck here, I am not sure if this is a good way to achieve my goal : **Create an instance of a class with a type defined by a string**

Error message : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

Comment: put a try/catch in the method and post the exact exception/inner exception being thrown. Also do you have to use a string type for the classname? why not just pass a type instead

Answer (score 0):

The class type would need to be "Full.CLASSName" or even better "Full.CLASSName,Assembly" to dynamically create the class.  For the former, the type would need to be in the same assembly, I believe.  So JS may be passing something up, but you have to make sure the type matches the type name .NET expects.

Comment: I verified, the string = to "test". And how can I verify the assembly ? Ty btw

Comment: Assembly just have to match the assembly name (DLL name).  If your class TestClass is in namespace Some.Namespace, and the DLL is TestProject.DLL, then your type name should be 'Some.Namespace.TestClass,TestProject'.  If it's in the GAC, then you need the strongly typed naming.